# Match string between two characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex command which gives me from a string the word which is between the last "`/`" and "`&`".

String:

> ://name.prod.something-blabla.com/erp/apps/appname/appname.text#/com/text/prod/appname/uil/partner/**PartnerBearbeiten**&unternehmenId1=Z0004dw

Desired output: **PartnerBearbeiten**

I tried: `([^\/]+\&)` but it includes the `&` (PartnerBearbeiten&)

Image: [Regex code in a xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxoXp.png)

Comment: If you don't want the `&` to be in the match, lookahead for `&`, or put it inside the negative character set?

Comment: and how does that look in the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
([^\/]+?)(?=&)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zNT7C6/2).

Note that I made character class lazy (using `+?`), in order to work with multi-parameters URL.

Comment: @LilJo glad! You can mark the answer as accepted if you want, that's the SO way to say *thanks*

Comment: This regex works great. If there is another "&" in the string, it doesn't work anymore. Is there a solution? New string:
://name.prod.something-blabla.com/erp/apps/appname/appname.text#/com/text/prod/appname/uil/partner/PartnerBearbeiten&unternehmenId1=Z0004dw&ErAngebot=423423-23123-44234-abs

Comment: Could you show us how you impemented the regex? @LilJo

Comment: I added a image on my question. I'm using a java application which loads a xml where the regex is located.

Comment: Try with `(?<=\/)([^\/]+?)(?=&)` @LilJo

Comment: Thank you very much @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex lookahead to exclude any matches from the result. So, to exclude `&` in that particular pattern, the regex would be `([^/]+(?=\&))` (check on this [RegExr website](https://regexr.com/42l04))

Comment: @LilJo ... the RegExp fails for more than just one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([^\/])*(?=&) <br>
```

Tested with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as shown in other answers is certainly possible here but I’d argue that the *canonical* solution to the problem of matching a substring between two delimiting characters is to exclude the last character from the match character class:

```
/([^/&]+)&
```

This has the advantage of making the overall expression simpler, and working *efficiently* without using non-greedy matching: using a lookahead assertion without non-greedy matching would force the regular expression to backtrack, which can be inefficient in this case (using non-greedy `+?` instead of `+` would also solve this, though).

Lookahead assertions are best reserved for cases that cannot be expressed differently. In this particular case, they are simply redundant.